# How to iterate a Vec<T> with the indexed position?

Tags: for-loop, rust, iterator

I need to iterate a `Vec` including the position for each iterated element. I'm sure this is already in the API but I cannot see it.

I need something like this:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1; 10];
    for (pos, e) in v.iter() {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You can use the [`Iterator::enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) method:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1; 10];
    for (pos, e) in v.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("Element at position {}: {:?}", pos, e);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=594ad9cb0e4d4ac0851f12a3cee0443d)

Comment: @Shepmaster Is there also a way to do this and get the element directly instead of a reference to it?

Comment: @Lukas [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/155423)

Comment: if we call .next(), and then enumerate(), it don't keep track of the real index