# What is the difference between iter and into_iter?

Tags: rust, iterator

I am doing the [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/closures/closure_examples/iter_find.html) tutorial, which has this code snippet:

```
// Vec example
let vec1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
let vec2 = vec![4, 5, 6];

// `iter()` for vecs yields `&i32`. Destructure to `i32`.
println!("2 in vec1: {}", vec1.iter()     .any(|&x| x == 2));
// `into_iter()` for vecs yields `i32`. No destructuring required.
println!("2 in vec2: {}", vec2.into_iter().any(| x| x == 2));

// Array example
let array1 = [1, 2, 3];
let array2 = [4, 5, 6];

// `iter()` for arrays yields `&i32`.
println!("2 in array1: {}", array1.iter()     .any(|&x| x == 2));
// `into_iter()` for arrays unusually yields `&i32`.
println!("2 in array2: {}", array2.into_iter().any(|&x| x == 2));
```

I am quite confused — for a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html), the iterator returned from [`.iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) yields references and the iterator returned from [`.into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#tymethod.into_iter) yields values, but for an [array](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) these iterators are identical?

What is the use case/API for these two methods?

Answer (score 482, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

- The iterator returned by `into_iter` may yield any of `T`, `&T` or `&mut T`, depending on the context.
- The iterator returned by `iter` will yield `&T`, by convention.
- The iterator returned by `iter_mut` will yield `&mut T`, by convention.

---

The first question is: "What is `into_iter`?"

`into_iter` comes from the [`IntoIterator` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html):

> ```
> pub trait IntoIterator 
> where
>     <Self::IntoIter as Iterator>::Item == Self::Item, 
> {
>     type Item;
>     type IntoIter: Iterator;
>     fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter;
> }
> ```

You implement this trait when you want to specify how a particular type is to be converted into an iterator. Most notably, if a type implements `IntoIterator` it can be used in a `for` loop.

For example, `Vec` implements `IntoIterator`... thrice!

> ```
> impl<T> IntoIterator for Vec<T>
> impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a Vec<T>
> impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a mut Vec<T>
> ```

Each variant is slightly different.

This one consumes the `Vec` and its iterator [yields **values**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator) (`T` directly):

> ```
> impl<T> IntoIterator for Vec<T> {
>     type Item = T;
>     type IntoIter = IntoIter<T>;
>
>     fn into_iter(mut self) -> IntoIter<T> { /* ... */ }
> }
> ```

The other two take the vector by reference (don't be fooled by the signature of `into_iter(self)` because `self` is a reference in both cases) and their iterators will produce references to the elements inside `Vec`.

This one [yields **immutable references**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator-1):

> ```
> impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a Vec<T> {
>     type Item = &'a T;
>     type IntoIter = slice::Iter<'a, T>;
>
>     fn into_iter(self) -> slice::Iter<'a, T> { /* ... */ }
> }
> ```

While this one [yields **mutable references**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator-2):

> ```
> impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a mut Vec<T> {
>     type Item = &'a mut T;
>     type IntoIter = slice::IterMut<'a, T>;
>
>     fn into_iter(self) -> slice::IterMut<'a, T> { /* ... */ }
> }
> ```

---

So:

> What is the difference between `iter` and `into_iter`?

`into_iter` is a generic method to obtain an iterator, whether this iterator yields values, immutable references or mutable references **is context dependent** and can sometimes be surprising.

`iter` and `iter_mut` are ad-hoc methods. Their return type is therefore independent of the context, and will conventionally be iterators yielding immutable references and mutable references, respectively.

The author of the Rust by Example post illustrates the surprise coming from the dependence on the context (i.e., the type) on which `into_iter` is called, and is also compounding the problem by using the fact that:

1. `IntoIterator` is not implemented for `[T; N]`, only for `&[T; N]` and `&mut [T; N]` -- it will be for Rust 2021.
2. When a method is not implemented for a value, it is automatically searched for *references* to that value instead

which is very surprising for `into_iter` since all types (except `[T; N]`) implement it for all 3 variations (value and references).

Arrays implement `IntoIterator` (in such a surprising fashion) to make it possible to iterate over references to them in `for` loops.

As of Rust 1.51, it's possible for the array to implement an iterator that yields values (via [`array::IntoIter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/array/struct.IntoIter.html)), but the existing implementation of `IntoIterator` that automatically references [makes it hard to implement by-value iteration via `IntoIterator`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/65819).

Comment: I found this blog post helpful: http://hermanradtke.com/2015/06/22/effectively-using-iterators-in-rust.html

Comment: >whether this iterator yields values, immutable references or mutable references is context dependent

What does it mean and how to deal with that? How one would force iter_mut to yield mutable values, for example?

Comment: @DanM.: (1) It means that `into_iter` picks an implementation based on whether the receiver is a value, reference or mutable reference. (2) There are no mutable values in Rust, or rather, any value is mutable since you have ownership.

Comment: @MatthieuM.hm, that doesn't seem to be the case in my tests. I've implemented IntoIter for `&'a MyStruct` and `&mut 'a MyStruct` and the first one was always chosen if present even if I called `into_iter().for_each()` on `mut` value with `&mut` arguments in lambda.

Comment: @DanM.: This seems strange to me; I would suggest posting a question with a [MCVE] reproducing this.

Comment: @MatthieuM. ok, but just to be sure, [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0aabde39ac19d98ba157ff9dbe34fad6) is not the expected behavior, is it?

Comment: @DanM.: It seems like a limitation of the type-inference/trait-selection mechanism to me, I'd still ask the question explicitly on SO with this example to see if there's a specific language rule for the behavior, or any work on improving things. It's notable that were you to use a for loop you'd need to write `&mut foo` too.

Comment: For arrays implementing `IntoIter`, see also https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65798.

Comment: I found this blog post helpful too, http://xion.io/post/code/rust-for-loop.html

Comment: Worth noting that arrays will implement `IntoIter` in rust 2021 edition, and they plan to backport it so it mostly works in all editions: https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/05/11/edition-2021.html

Comment: For the people who are curious about `2. When a method is not implemented for a value, it is automatically searched for references to that value instead`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28552082/14092446) out.

Answer (score 355):

I came here from Google seeking a simple answer which wasn't provided by the other answers. Here's that simple answer:

- `iter()` iterates over the items by reference
- `iter_mut()` iterates over the items, giving a mutable reference to each item
- `into_iter()` iterates over the items, moving them into the new scope

So `for x in my_vec { ... }` is essentially equivalent to `my_vec.into_iter().for_each(|x| ... )` - both `move` the elements of `my_vec` into the `...` scope.

If you just need to *look at* the data, use `iter`, if you need to edit/mutate it, use `iter_mut`, and if you need to give it a new owner, use `into_iter`.

This was helpful: http://hermanradtke.com/2015/06/22/effectively-using-iterators-in-rust.html

Comment: This is the good simple answer for the (common?) case where `my_vec` or whatever you are calling `.into_iter()` on is in fact a `Vec<T>`. The other answers are more complicated to also mention that, if you call `.into_iter()` on other things such as a `&Vec<T>` or `&[]` (or equivalently, try to iterate over them in a `for ... in ... ` loop), you might not actually be moving the items into the new scope. (At least, that's my understanding so far...)

Comment: Yeah, "`into_iter()` iterates over the items, moving them into the new scope" is not always accurate - see the accepted answer for more details.

Answer (score 24):

I think there's something to clarify a bit more. Collection types, such as `Vec<T>` and `VecDeque<T>`, have `into_iter` method that yields `T` because they implement `IntoIterator<Item=T>`. There's nothing to stop us to create a type `Foo<T>` if which is iterated over, it will yield not `T` but another type `U`. That is, `Foo<T>` implements `IntoIterator<Item=U>`.

In fact, there are some examples in `std`: `&Path` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#impl-IntoIterator) `IntoIterator<Item=&OsStr>` and `&UnixListener` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/net/struct.UnixListener.html#impl-IntoIterator) `IntoIterator<Item=Result<UnixStream>>`.

---

### The difference between `into_iter` and `iter`

Back to the original question on the difference between `into_iter` and `iter`. Similar to what others have pointed out, the difference is that `into_iter` is a required method of [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) which can yield any type specified in [`IntoIterator::Item`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#associatedtype.Item). Typically, if a type implements `IntoIterator<Item=I>`, by convention it has also two ad-hoc methods: `iter` and `iter_mut` which yield `&I` and `&mut I`, respectively.

What it implies is that we can create a function that receives a type that has `into_iter` method (i.e. it is an iterable) by using a trait bound:

```
fn process_iterable<I: IntoIterator>(iterable: I) {
    for item in iterable {
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, we can't<sup>*</sup> use a trait bound to require a type to have `iter` method or `iter_mut` method, because they're just conventions. We can say that `into_iter` is more widely useable than `iter` or `iter_mut`.

#### Alternatives to `iter` and `iter_mut`

Another interesting thing to observe is that `iter` is not the only way to get an iterator that yields `&T`. By convention (again), collection types `SomeCollection<T>` in `std` which have `iter` method also have their immutable reference types `&SomeCollection<T>` implement `IntoIterator<Item=&T>`. For example, `&Vec<T>` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator) `IntoIterator<Item=&T>`, so it enables us to iterate over `&Vec<T>`:

```
let v = vec![1, 2];

// Below is equivalent to: `for item in v.iter() {`
for item in &v {
    println!("{}", item);
}
```

If `v.iter()` is equivalent to `&v` in that both implement `IntoIterator<Item=&T>`, why then does Rust provide both? It's for ergonomics. In `for` loops, it's a bit more concise to use `&v` than `v.iter()`; but in other cases, `v.iter()` is a lot clearer than `(&v).into_iter()`:

```
let v = vec![1, 2];

let a: Vec<i32> = v.iter().map(|x| x * x).collect();
// Although above and below are equivalent, above is a lot clearer than below.
let b: Vec<i32> = (&v).into_iter().map(|x| x * x).collect();
```

Similarly, in `for` loops, `v.iter_mut()` can be replaced with `&mut v`:

```
let mut v = vec![1, 2];

// Below is equivalent to: `for item in v.iter_mut() {`
for item in &mut v {
    *item *= 2;
}
```

---

### When to provide (implement) `into_iter` and `iter` methods for a type

If the type has only one “way” to be iterated over, we should implement both. However, if there are two ways or more it can be iterated over, we should instead provide an ad-hoc method for each way.

For example, `String` provides neither `into_iter` nor `iter` because there are two ways to iterate it: to iterate its representation in bytes or to iterate its representation in characters. Instead, it provides two methods: [`bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.bytes) for iterating the bytes and [`chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.chars) for iterating the characters, as alternatives to `iter` method.

---

<sup>*</sup> Well, technically we can do it by creating a trait. But then we need to `impl` that trait for each type we want to use. Meanwhile, many types in `std` already implement `IntoIterator`.

Answer (score 9):

`.into_iter()` is not implemented for a array itself, but only `&[]`. Compare:

```
impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a [T]
    type Item = &'a T
```

with

```
impl<T> IntoIterator for Vec<T>
    type Item = T
```

Since `IntoIterator` is defined only on `&[T]`, the slice itself cannot be dropped the same way as `Vec` when you use the values. (values cannot be moved out)

Now, why that's the case is a different issues, and I'd like to learn myself. Speculating: array is the data itself, slice is only a view into it. In practice you cannot move the array as a value into another function, just pass a view of it, so you cannot consume it there either.

Comment: `IntoIterator` is also implemented for `&'a mut [T]`, so it _could_ move the objects out of the array. I think that it is related to the fact that the return struct `IntoIter<T>` does not have a lifetime argument while `Iter<'a, T>` does, so the former cannot hold a slice.

Comment: `mut` means that you can change the values, not that you can move them out.

Comment: @rodrigo `let mut a = ["abc".to_string()]; a.into_iter().map(|x| { *x });` => "error: cannot move out of borrowed content"

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right and values cannot be moved from the array. However, I still think that it should be possible to implement a kind of `ArrayIntoIter` struct using unsafe Rust, as part of the library... Maybe not worth it, as you should use `Vec` for those cases anyway.

Comment: so I don't understand... is that the reason that `array.into_iter` returns `&T` - because it is doing magic to automatically convert it to `&array.into_iter` -- and if so, I don't understand what that has to do with moving values or not moving values. Or is it as @rodrigo said, that you get the reference simply because (for some reason) you *cannot move values out of arrays*? Still very confused.

Comment: related: what does "moving" mean under the covers? I was under the impression that it meant that it literally "moves" the data (for instance from the stack to the heap). Also, is "moving" the same thing as getting something "by value"?

Comment: So one by one: Yes, `into_iter` returns `&T`, because you're really calling `&array.into_iter()`. This is not really magical - it happens automatically for all methods (needed & will be added automatically). Not being able to move the array was just a side comment that's slightly related; it may or may not explain the answer. Moving the value means it is not valid in the previous location anymore and is instead present in the new one. This happens for `vec2` for example. At the end of this code, you can access `vec1[0]`, but not `vec2[0]`.

Comment: @rodrigo that `IntoIterator` is implemented for `&mut [T]` *does not* imply that it is possible to move objects out of an array. It is not possible: all array items must always be initialized in Rust, and the only way to move something out of a (mutable) slice is to use `std:::mem::replace()` and similar functions. Also, because Rust does not have type-level integers yet, it is not possible to write an implementation of by-value `IntoIterator` for arrays - you'd need a separate implementation for every array size, which without type-level integers is absolutely unwieldy.

Answer (score 2):

`IntoIterator` and `Iterator` are usually used like this.

We implement `IntoIterator` for structures that has an inner/nested value (or is behind a reference) that either implements `Iterator` or has an intermediate "Iter" structure.

For example, lets create a "new" data structure:

```
struct List<T>; 
// Looks something like this:
// - List<T>(Option<Box<ListCell<T>>>)
// - ListCell<T> { value: T, next: List<T> }
```

We want this `List<T>` to be iterable, so this should be a good place to implement `Iterator` right? Yes, we could do that, but that would limit us in certain ways.

Instead we create an intermediate "iterable" structure and implement the `Iterator` trait:

```
// NOTE: I have removed all lifetimes to make it less messy.
struct ListIter<T> { cursor: &List<T> };
impl<T> Iterator for ListIter<T> {
  type Item = &T;
  fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {...}
}
```

So now we need to somehow connect `List<T>` and `ListIter<T>`. This can be done by implementing `IntoIterator` for List.

```
impl<T> IntoIterator for List<T> {
    type Item = T;
    type Iter = ListIter<Self::Item>; 
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::Iter { ListIter { cursor: &self } }
}
```

`IntoIterator` can also be implemented multiple times for container struct if for example it contains different nested iterable fields or we have some higher kinded type situation.

Lets say we have a `Collection<T>: IntoIterator` trait that will be implemented by multiple data structures, e.g. `List<T>`, `Vector<T>` and `Tree<T>` that also have their respective Iter; `ListIter<T>`, `VectorIter<T>` and `TreeIter<T>`. But what does this actually mean when we go from generic to specific code?

```
fn wrapper<C>(value: C) where C: Collection<i32> {
  let iter = value.into_iter() // But what iterator are we?
  ...
}
```

> This code is not 100% correct, lifetimes and mutability support are omitted.

Answer (score 2):

I found very simple and clear example code,

Items in an iterator made with

- `iter` will be a reference
- `into_iter` will be an owned value
- `iter_mut` will be a mutable reference

```rust
#[test]
fn iter_demo() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let mut v1_iter = v1.iter();

    // iter() returns an iterator of slices.
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(&1));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(&2));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(&3));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), None);
}

#[test]
fn into_iter_demo() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let mut v1_iter = v1.into_iter();

    // into_iter() returns an iterator from a value.
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(1));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(2));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(3));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), None);
}

#[test]
fn iter_mut_demo() {
    let mut v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let mut v1_iter = v1.iter_mut();

    // iter_mut() returns an iterator that allows modifying each value.
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(&mut 1));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(&mut 2));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), Some(&mut 3));
    assert_eq!(v1_iter.next(), None);
}
```

https://gist.github.com/philipjkim/98bc460d31773255fd2b20780a73b742

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35670541)