# Iterating over a slice's values instead of references in Rust?

Tags: iterator, rust

When looping over a slice of structs, the value I get is a reference (which is fine), however in some cases it's annoying to have to write `var` as `(*var)` in many places.

Is there a better way to avoid re-declaring the variable?

```
fn my_fn(slice: &[MyStruct]) {
    for var in slice {
        let var = *var;  // <-- how to avoid this?

        // Without the line above, errors in comments occur:

        other_fn(var);  // <-- expected struct `MyStruct`, found reference

        if var != var.other {
            // ^^ trait `&MyStruct: std::cmp::PartialEq<MyStruct>>` not satisfied
            foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can remove the reference by destructuring in [the pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html#for-loops) ([old link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160602130906/http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html)):

```
//  |
//  v
for &var in slice {
    other_fn(var);
}
```

*However*, this only works **for `Copy`-types**! If you have a type that doesn't implement `Copy` but does implement `Clone`, you could use the `cloned()` iterator adapter; see [Chris Emerson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40613839/155423) for more information.

Comment: Hi , love this answer, but I could not find how this is ["destructuring" in a pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html)... maybe I can think of it like [how `&` could be used in function parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-01-all-the-places-for-patterns.html#function-parameters)... Need to learn more about what `&var` does in front of a pattern...

Comment: Maybe ampersand before a pattern is a ["reference pattern"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/patterns.html#reference-patterns)? This description from my link sounds like what you're doing: "Reference patterns dereference the pointers that are being matched and, thus, borrow them." ... but then in the example, they use asterisk (`*`) not ampersand (`&`)... like this: 
 `*int_reference` ... oh, but in the *pattern* itself, they use ampersand: `&0`.

Comment: So if it *does* implement `Copy` types, then could do this too, as per Chris Emerson's answer: 
`for var in slice.iter().copied() {
    other_fn(var);
}`

Comment: @NateAnderson you got it, that's exactly what this pattern destructuring is. And yes the `copied()` solution works as well.

Answer (score 42):

In some cases you can iterate directly on values if you can consume the iterable, e.g. using [`Vec::into_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator-1).

With slices, you can use [`cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) or [`copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) on the iterator:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let slice = &v[..];
    for u in slice.iter().cloned() {
        let u: usize = u; // prove it's really usize, not &usize
        println!("{}", u);
    }
}
```

This relies on the item implementing [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) or [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html), but if it doesn't you probably do want references after all.

Comment: This is not as memory efficient as Lukas' answer. Additionally, `slice` isn't mutable, so while the iterator might be consumed, `slice` itself won't be so cloning isn't needed.

Comment: @EliSadoff Actually, both of our solutions will probably result in the same optimized assembly output. Not the complete slice or iterator is cloned, but each element that is yielded.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt You're right. I also didn't think about the `Clone` vs. `Copy` thing which this accounts for.

Comment: More valuable than the accepted answer because it brings up `into_iter()`. What I really needed was to know the difference from `iter()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter

Comment: @VictorSergienko `iter()` and `into_iter()` on a slice are exactly the same thing: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/fd9ca0c25ec90f6ed156e6f0e950763ca5171f8a/library/core/src/slice/iter.rs#L23