# How do I filter values from a Vec and still return a Vec?

Tags: filter, rust

I have a function that takes a `&Vec<Word>` (where `Word` is a locally defined type) and that should return a `Vec<Word>` (or a `&Vec<Word>`). The function's definition consists in filtering values from the argument:

```
fn possibleWords(w1: &Word, words: &Vec<Word>) -> Vec<Word> {
    words.into_iter().filter(|w| matches(w, w1)).collect::<Vec<Word>>()
}
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<[char; 10]>: std::iter::FromIterator<&[char; 10]>` is not satisfied

words.into_iter().filter(|w| matches(w, w1)).collect::<Vec<Word>>()
                                             ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<[char; 10]>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&[char; 10]`
```

I don't want to return a slice, I really want a `Vec`. Is there a way to do it without manually building a `Vec` from the slice?

Here is a MCVE:

```
type Word = [char; 10];

fn matches(w1: &Word, w2: &Word) -> bool {
    true
}

fn possibleWords(w1: &Word, words: &Vec<Word>) -> Vec<Word> {
    words.into_iter().filter(|w| matches(w, w1)).collect::<Vec<Word>>()
}


fn main() {
    let w1 = ['D', 'E', 'C', 'O', 'U', 'V', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'E'];
    let w2 = ['D', 'E', 'C', 'O', 'U', 'V', 'E', 'R', 'E', 'Z'];
    let words = vec![w1, w2];
    println!("{:?}", possibleWords(&w1, &words));
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you're trying to build a `Vec<Word>` from an iterator of `&Word`. Try inserting a `.cloned()` just before the `collect` method.

Comment: In order to call the `into_iter` method, you must pass the vector itself to the function, not a reference to it.

Comment: Well, @Milack27, it seems to work, thanks! I'll have to dig it to understand what's actually happening there, but I know where to look now.

Comment: Relevant: [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter).

Comment: `possibleWords` should take `&[Word]` instead of `&Vec<Word>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/3650362

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling the `into_iter` method on a `&Vec<Word>`, which gives you an `Iterator<&Word>`. When you try to collect the elements from this iterator, you'll get a collection of `&Word` although you wanted a collection of `Word`.

You have two options to fix this:

1. Convert the `Iterator<&Word>` into an `Iterator<Word>` by cloning each element (call the `cloned` method on the iterator);
2. Pass a `Vec<Word>` to the function, instead of a `&Vec<Word>`. This way, the `into_iter` method will return an `Iterator<Word>`, from which you can collect with no problem.