# Collecting from Iterator<Item=&T> to Vec<T>

Tags: rust

I'm trying out Rust again and making a function to remove every other element:

```
fn remove_every_other(arr: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
    arr.iter().step_by(2).collect::<Vec<_>>()
}
```

But then I was hit with this error:

```
  |
1 | fn remove_every_other(arr: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
  |                                      ------- expected `Vec<u8>` because of return type
2 |     arr.iter().step_by(2).collect::<Vec<_>>()
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `u8`, found `&u8`
  |
  = note: expected struct `Vec<u8>`
             found struct `Vec<&u8>`
```

That's an easy fix for me, just map and dereference, right?

```rs
arr.iter().step_by(2).map(|x| *x).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

However, I don't think this is the right way... it feels dirty.

I also tried using `into_iter` because [in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/#the-three-forms-of-iteration), it was listed to return `T` and not `&T`, but using it gives me the same error.

Is there a "cleaner" or better way to do this?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=06de65a445bf602c68977ab812f7e36a)

Comment: [Similar question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115999/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-of-converting-a-vec-of-references-to-a-vec-of-values)

Comment: Honestly, might need to update the part about the three forms of iteration... `into_iter` returns `T`, `&T`, and `&mut T` depending on the context... But they were specifically talking about collections so I suppose that's excusable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I just read the entire page of documentation to find these two methods:

[`copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied):

```
arr.iter().step_by(2).copied().collect()
```

[`cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned):

```
arr.iter().step_by(2).cloned().collect()
```

However, this won't work for all `T`, only ones that implement `Copy` or `Clone`.

Comment: If `T` is neither `Copy` nor `Clone`, your function must take the input by value (e.g. `fn remove_every_other(arr: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8>`), and then you can use `arr.into_iter`.

Comment: Just to add to @Jmb's comment, you could accept a parameter of type `impl IntoIterator<Type = u8>` in order that anything implementing the trait will be accepted rather than being explicit that you require a `Vec<u8>` or whatever.  You may even prefer to accept an `impl Iterator<Type = u8>` if you want callers to be able to provide some arbitrary iterator that produces such values rather than a collection of them.