# Filter items that dont meet condition

Tags: rust

Suppose I got this vector: `let vec = vec![0,2,4,6,8]` and this range: `let range = 0..10`.
I want to collect all values inside a vec that are not part of the range, so my resulting vector should look like this: `[1,3,5,7,9]`

I tried it like this:

```
fn main() {
    let range = 0..10;
    let vec = vec![0,2,4,6,8];

    let x = vec.iter().filter(|&x| !range.contains(x)).collect::<Vec<&i32>>();

    println!("{:?}",x);
}
```

I tried to inverse the result of `contains()` with a `!`, but it has not influence on the result.

Also how would I collect this into a `vec<i32>` instead of `&i32`.

Comment: The problem statement is misguided. If you wish to collect all values in `vec` which are not part of the range `0..10`, you would get an empty sequence because all of `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]` are inside the range. To get the output `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`, the problem statement would be getting all values of the range `0..10` which are not present in the given vector `vec`.

Comment: _"Also how would I collect this into a `Vec<i32>` instead of `&i32`"_ duplicate of [What is the idiomatic way of converting a Vec of references to a Vec of values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53115999)

Comment: @E_net4 Thanks! I will look if I can solve this the other way around. Makes definitely more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from contradiction in question (which elements should be included - those inside, or those outside the range), I will assume that you want to *keep* elements that are *in range*, you have two solutions. You can either modify vector in place (1), or create a new vector, to which you copy values in range (2).

In the first case you can simply use [Vec::retain](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain)

```rust
use std::ops::RangeBounds;

pub fn filter_in_place<T, R>(data: &mut Vec<T>, range: R)
where
    R: RangeBounds<T>,
    T: PartialOrd,
{
    data.retain(|x| range.contains(x));
}
```

In the second case you can use [Iterator::filter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) combined with [Iterator::copied](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied)

```rust
use std::ops::RangeBounds;

pub fn filter<T, R>(data: &[T], range: R) -> Vec<T>
where
    R: RangeBounds<T>,
    T: PartialOrd + Copy,
{
    data.iter().copied().filter(|x| range.contains(x)).collect()
}
```