# Cannot move out borrowed content inside closure

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Rust newbie here. I'm trying to write a function which consumes the passed vector, modifies it, appends it to another vector and returns it.

Here is my code:

```
fn try(other: Vec<(String, String)>) -> Vec<(String, String)> {
    let mut res = Vec::new();
    let mut neg: Vec<(String,String)> = other
                                        .iter()
                                        .map(|t| (t.0, String::from("abc")))
                                        .collect();
    res.append(&mut neg);
    res
}
```

However, I'm getting a `cannot move out borrowed content` at `t.0`. What is it that I'm doing wrong? What's getting passed into the closure?

Comment: `.iter()` returns an iterator to references of each element in the vector. You seem to want `into_iter()`.

Comment: What's the point of `res`? Why not just return `neg` directly?

Comment: @E_net4 I wouldn't call that question a duplicate. That question you link you would only ask if you already know that you should use `into_iter` here. The answer to the question is quite relevant though. (Also, the best solution here is actually not to use `into_iter` at all, but just modify the original vector and return it.)

Comment: @M-ou-se It's the answer that really matters when choosing a duplicate target. A question being a duplicate does not mean that the target question is exactly the same, but that its answers also address that problem. As for whether it's a good duplicate target or not, I'll leave the decision to the remaining voters.

Comment: thanks a lot. i agree with the comments. it was a matter of knowing that into_iter was to be used in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.0` tries to *move* the `String` out of the tuple that `t` refers to, but `t` only borrows it. That's because `.iter()` gives you an iterator that gives you references to the values. If you use `into_iter()` instead of `iter()` you get to *consume* all the values of `other`, instead of only getting to *borrow* them, because `other.into_iter()` consumes `other`.

In your specific example, it would be more efficient to completely re-use `other` instead of creating a new `Vec` with the contents (partially) taken from `other`, and then dropping `other`:

```rust
fn try2(mut other: Vec<(String, String)>) -> Vec<(String, String)> {
    for x in &mut other {
        x.1 = String::from("abc");
    }
    other
}
```

It could be even more efficient to re-use the `String`s as well, instead of creating new ones with `String::from`.

Comment: How does your answer differ from the suggested duplicate [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter)?

Comment: @hellow That question only handles the first part. Showing that `into_iter()` and `collect()` is not the best option in this case is quite a relevant part that is not handled in that question/answer.