# cannot move out of `*h` which is behind a shared reference

Tags: rust

I'm trying to call join on a vector of `JoinHandle`, using `for_each`. I get this error:

```
let mut threads = vec![];
...
threads.iter().for_each(|h| h.join().unwrap());

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*h` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:41:33
   |
41 |     threads.iter().for_each(|h| h.join().unwrap());
   |                                 ^ move occurs because `*h` has type `std::thread::JoinHandle<()>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

As far as I can tell, this should work fine if I were given references to the `JoinHandle`s by `for_each`, but it seems I'm not. The following code works fine:

```
for h in threads {
    h.join().unwrap();
}
```

How do I do the same but using `for_each` or something similar to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [`into_iter` instead of `iter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter). With `iter` you only get references of items, while `join` has a signature as `pub fn join(self) -> Result<T>` which requires owned data as parameter:

```
threads.into_iter().for_each(|h| { h.join().unwrap(); });
```

should work.