# Rust borrowing rules in `for...in` loop

Tags: rust, borrowing

Why would all these three `print_max` functions work? Which one is the best practice? Is `for number in number_list` a shortcut for `for number in number_list.iter()`?

```rust
fn main() {
    let number_list = vec![34, 50, 25, 100, 65];

    print_max_1(&number_list);
    print_max_2(&number_list);
    print_max_3(&number_list);
}

fn print_max_1(number_list: &[u16]) {
    let mut largest = &number_list[0]; // borrow the first number
    for number in number_list.iter() { // borrowing?
        if number > largest {
            largest = number;
        }
    }
    println!("The largest number is {}", largest);
}

fn print_max_2(number_list: &[u16]) {
    let mut largest = &number_list[0]; // borrow the first number
    for number in number_list {        // shortcut for .iter()?
        if number > largest {
            largest = number;
        }
    }
    println!("The largest number is {}", largest);
} 

fn print_max_3(number_list: &[u16]) {
    let mut largest = number_list[0];    // copying?
    for &number in number_list.iter() {  // borrowing?
        if number > largest {            // no error
            largest = number;
        }
    }
    println!("The largest number is {}", largest);
}
```

Why wouldn't this work?

```rust
fn print_max_4(number_list: &[u16]) {
    let mut largest = &number_list[0];
    for &number in number_list {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number;
        }
    }
    println!("The largest number is {}", largest);
}
```

The error message says that `largest` is `&u16` while `number` is `u16`. Why isn't `number` `&u16`?

Comment: In general, borrowing `u16` is rather silly since (ignoring any optimizer that the compiler may be performing here) you're using _more_ stack space to store a pointer that you still need to dereference to access the orignial `u16`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's tackle these one-by-one.

#### `print_max_1`

Here, `largest` is a mutable variable that holds an immutable reference to a `u16` (i.e. it holds a `&u16`). Within the loop, `number` is also a `&u16` which, like `largest`, is borrowed from `number_list`. Both `number` and `larger` are implicitly dereferenced to perform the comparison. If the value referenced by `number` is greater than that referenced by `larger`, you store a copy of the immutable reference contained in `number` into `largest`.

#### `print_max_2`

In this case, since `number_list` is itself borrowed, the analysis of `print_max_2` is identical to `print_max_1`.

#### `print_max_3`

Here, `largest` is a `u16`. You are correct that `number_list[0]` is copied, but it is worth noting that this copy is *cheap*. Within the loop, each element of `number_list` is copied and stored directly in `number`. If `number` is greater than `largest`, you stored the new greatest value directly in `largest`. This is the most optimal of the three implementations you've written, since you do away with all of the unnecessary indirection that references (i.e., pointers) introduce.

#### `print_max_4`

Once again, you store a reference to the first element of `number_list` in `largest`, i.e. `largest` is a `&u16`. Similarly, as was the case in `print_max_3`, `number` is a `u16`, which will hold copies of the elements from `number_list`. However, as you noted, this function is the problem child.

Within the loop, the compiler will point out two errors:

1. You attempt to compare two distinct types which don't have a [`PartialOrder`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html) defined, namely `largest` which is a `&u16` and `number` which is a `u16`. Rust isn't in the business of trying to guess what you mean by this comparison, so in order fix this, you'll have to make both `number` and `largest` the same type. In this case, what you want to do is explicitly dereference `largest` using the `*` operator, which will allow you to compare the `u16` it points to with the `u16` contained in `number`. This final comparison looks like

   ```
   if number > *largest { ... }
   ```
2. You attempt to store a `u16` in a variable of type `&u16`, which does not make sense. Unfortunately, here you're going to run into a wall. Within the loop, all you have is the value of the number you copied from `number_list`, but `largest` needs to hold a *reference* to a `u16`. We can't simply borrow `number` here (e.g. by writing `largest = &number`), since `number` will be dropped (i.e. go out of scope) at the end of the loop. The only way to resolve is is to revert by to `print_max_2` by storing the maximum *value* itself instead of the pointer to it.

As for whether `for number in number_list` is a shortcut for `for number in number_list.iter()`, the answer is a firm **no**. The former will take ownership of `number_list`, and during each iteration, `number` takes ownership of the next value in `number_list`. In contrasts, the latter only performs a borrow, and during each iteration of the loop, `number` receives an immutable reference to the next element of `number_list`.

In this specific case, these two operation appear identical, since taking ownership of an immutable reference simply entails making a copy, which leaves the original owner intact. For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57697614/11082165) to a related question on the difference between `.into_iter()` and `.iter()`.

Comment: I think llvm would optimize all of these equally, pointers or not? Would be really surprised to see codegen differences in godbolt

Comment: @Brian Could you give some rust-doc references for the explanation of `print_max_1()`: "Both `number` and `largest`, (are `&u16`, and) are implicitly dereferenced to perform the comparison."? Thanks.

Comment: @mitnk See [this `impl`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/cmp.rs.html#1178-1191) from `cmp.rs` in the standard library. Since you asked for a doc reference, other relelvant reading may include TRPL 2018, [15.2 Implicit Deref Coercions with Functions and Methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.29.0/book/2018-edition/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods) (not in play in here), and similarly, the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) and [`PartialOrd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialOrd.html) traits.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things happening auto-magically here to note:

Your variable 'number_list' is a [`std::vec::Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html). You then use a slice for the function argument signatures. Vector has an implementation for the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Deref) trait. In rust, this particular arrangement uses [`Deref coercion`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.29.0/book/first-edition/deref-coercions.html) to convert the vector with mentioned Deref trait into a [`std::slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/index.html).

However, both vectors and slices can be iterated by using a for loop. Anything that implements the [`std::iter::Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) trait.
The vector doesn't do this, but rather implements [`std::iter::IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html), which as it puts it, `By implementing IntoIterator for a type, you define how it will be converted to an iterator. This is common for types which describe a collection of some kind.`
Take a look at [Implementing an Iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#implementing-iterator) for more details. Specifically the lines:

> all `Iterators` implement `IntoIterator`, by just returning themselves.
> This means two things:
>
> If you're writing an Iterator, you can use it with a for loop. If
> you're creating a collection, implementing `IntoIterator` for it will
> allow your collection to be used with the for loop.

You'll find that Rust provides a lot of conversion traits, and some automatic hidden behavior. With the extensive type use in Rust, this helps alleviate some of the necessary conversions. See [From and Into](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/conversion/from_into.html) for more details there.

I hated this about C++ (hidden code), however it's not so bad in Rust. If the compiler lets you do it, then you've probably found what you need. Sometimes, the automatic way may not be adequate, and you may need to use supporting methods/functions to get there.