# How does iter() differ to a plain iteration over a HashMap?

Tags: for-loop, rust, hashmap, ownership

Take the following code snippet:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut en_fr_map: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
    en_fr_map.insert(String::from("Hello"), String::from("Bonjour"));
    en_fr_map.insert(String::from("World"), String::from("Monde"));

    for (key, value) in en_fr_map {
        println!("key is {} and value is {}", key, value);
    }
}
```

Which compiles fines and spits out the following output:

```sh
key is Hello and value is Bonjour
key is World and value is Monde
```

Now, if I change the for loop to this:

```rust
for (key, value) in en_fr_map.iter() {
    println!("key is {} and value is {}", key, value);
}
```

That is, calling the `iter()` function on the map, the result is the same. How are they different?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/iter.html

Comment: A `for` loop implicitly calls `into_iter()` on the value passed to it. See also [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/7246614)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between iter and into\_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter)

Comment: Yes @timotree. Your clarification that a for loop implicitly calls `into_iter()` was particularly helpful.