# How to implement nom::InputIter for a Vec of tokens?

Tags: rust, nom

I'm building a parser using [nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom/) and I'd like to use nom combinators to process tokenized input.

The stream of tokens is represented by `Vec<Token<S>>`, with `Token` being:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum Token<S> {
    Identifier(S),
    String(S),
}
```

I tried to implement `InputIter` for a vector of arbitrary values:

```rust
impl<'a, T> InputIter for Vec<T> {
    type Item = T;
    type Iter = Enumerate<Self::IterElem>;
    type IterElem = Iter<'a, Self::Item>;

    fn iter_indices(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        self.iter().enumerate()
    }

    fn iter_elements(&self) -> Self::IterElem {
        self.iter()
    }
}
```

When I encountered the following error:

```
error[E0207]: the lifetime parameter `'a` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/lex/tokens.rs:37:6
   |
37 | impl<'a, T> InputIter for Vec<T> {
   |      ^^ unconstrained lifetime parameter
```

I then tried to constrain the lifetime parameter using the type parameter `Token<S>`:

```rust
impl<'a> InputIter for Vec<Token<&'a str>> {
    type Item = Token<&'a str>;
    type Iter = Enumerate<Self::IterElem>;
    type IterElem = Iter<'a, Self::Item>;

    fn iter_indices(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        self.iter().enumerate()
    }

    fn iter_elements(&self) -> Self::IterElem {
        self.iter()
    }
}
```

Which led to the following:

```
error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types
  --> src/lex/tokens.rs:51:1
   |
51 | impl<'a> InputIter for Vec<Token<&'a str>> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-------------------
   | |                      |
   | |                      `std::vec::Vec` is not defined in the current crate
   | impl doesn't use only types from inside the current crate
   |
   = note: define and implement a trait or new type instead
```

The error seems to imply that I can't implement an outside trait for an outside type, so I'm trying to wrap `Vec<Token<S>>` into a custom struct:

```
struct Tokens<S> {
    vec: Vec<Token<S>>,
}

impl<'a> InputIter for Tokens<&'a str> {
    type Item = Token<&'a str>;
    type Iter = Enumerate<Self::IterElem>;
    type IterElem = Iter<'a, Self::Item>;

    fn iter_indices(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        self.vec.iter().enumerate()
    }

    fn iter_elements(&self) -> Self::IterElem {
        self.vec.iter()
    }
}
```

Which results in the following error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::iter::Enumerate<std::slice::Iter<'_, lex::tokens::Token<&str>>> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == (usize, lex::tokens::Token<&str>)`
  --> src/lex/tokens.rs:56:3
   |
55 | impl<'a> InputIter for Tokens<&'a str> {
   | -------------------------------------- in this `impl` item
56 |   type Item = Token<&'a str>;
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected reference, found enum `lex::tokens::Token`
   |
   = note: expected tuple `(_, &lex::tokens::Token<&str>)`
              found tuple `(_, lex::tokens::Token<&str>)`
```

Does this mean I'm restricted to using a vector of references as opposed to a vector containing tokens directly? What gives? There doesn't seem to be anything in the [`InputIter`](https://docs.rs/nom/5.1.1/nom/trait.InputIter.html) declaration to imply this constraint.

Is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do and represent token stream in a way that is compatible with nom combinators?

A reproducible example [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b7edd9b410ec224b4353b1ee7ee4591d):

```
use std::iter::Enumerate;
use std::slice::Iter;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum Token<S> {
    Identifier(S),
    String(S),
}

struct Tokens<S> {
    vec: Vec<Token<S>>,
}

pub trait InputIter {
    type Item;
    type Iter: Iterator<Item = (usize, Self::Item)>;
    type IterElem: Iterator<Item = Self::Item>;

    fn iter_indices(&self) -> Self::Iter;
    fn iter_elements(&self) -> Self::IterElem;
}

impl<'a> InputIter for Tokens<&'a str> {
    type Item = Token<&'a str>;
    type Iter = Enumerate<Self::IterElem>;
    type IterElem = Iter<'a, Token<&'a str>>;

    fn iter_indices(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        self.vec.iter().enumerate()
    }

    fn iter_elements(&self) -> Self::IterElem {
        self.vec.iter()
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::slice::Iter<'_, Token<&str>> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == Token<&str>`
  --> src/main.rs:24:5
   |
23 | impl<'a> InputIter for Tokens<&'a str> {
   | -------------------------------------- in this `impl` item
24 |     type Item = Token<&'a str>;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected reference, found enum `Token`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&Token<&str>`
                   found enum `Token<&str>`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::iter::Enumerate<std::slice::Iter<'_, Token<&str>>> as std::iter::Iterator>::Item == (usize, Token<&str>)`
  --> src/main.rs:24:5
   |
23 | impl<'a> InputIter for Tokens<&'a str> {
   | -------------------------------------- in this `impl` item
24 |     type Item = Token<&'a str>;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected reference, found enum `Token`
   |
   = note: expected tuple `(_, &Token<&str>)`
              found tuple `(_, Token<&str>)`
```

Comment: @Stargateur Updated with a link to the playground.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Switching from `Iter` to `IntoIter` and calling `vec.into_iter()` helped me finish the implementation. I think the right question to ask now is if it would be possible to use `Vec<T>` with nom combinators without intorducing an intermediate structure. Please advise me if I should make it a new question or update the current one and remove intermediate steps?