# What is the idiomatic way to transform vector of structs to another vector of structs

Tags: rust, reference, iterator, move, borrowing

My function takes a `Vec` of structs as a parameter and places each of it's element into another vector as a new structure field:

```
fn new(cards: Vec<Card<'t>>) -> Self {
        CardsConnection {
            edges: cards.iter().map(|c| CardsConnectionEdge {
                cursor: c.id.clone(),
                node: *c
            }).collect::<Vec<CardsConnectionEdge>>()
        }
    }
```

I really want a move, so only new vector should own the `Card` instances. So since map got a reference, I want do dereference it to move the value, but I got the following error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*c` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/model.rs:74:23
   |
74 |                 node: *c
   |                       ^^ move occurs because `*c` has type `model::Card<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to previous error; 8 warnings emitted
```

While this non "functional-style" code works fine:

```
fn new(cards: Vec<Card<'t>>) -> Self {
        let mut edges = Vec::<CardsConnectionEdge>::with_capacity(cards.len());

        for c in cards {
            edges.push(CardsConnectionEdge {
                cursor: c.id.clone()
                node: c
            })
        }

        CardsConnection {
            edges
        }
    }
```

but looks a bit clumsy.

It there a way to do the same thing using iterators or some kind of map function? Or what is the idiomatic way of solving this kind of problems?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `into_iter()` The `iter` function iterates over the items by reference, while `into_iter` iterates over the items, moving them into a new scope.

So `for c in cards {...}` is essentially the same as `cards.into_iter().for_each(|c| ... )`. Both move the elements of cards into the `...` scope.

```rust
fn new(cards: Vec<Card<'t>>) -> Self {
    CardsConnection {
        edges: cards
            .into_iter()
            .map(|c| CardsConnectionEdge {
                cursor: c.id.clone(),
                node: c,
            })
            .collect(),
    }
}
```

*[Reference: iter vs. into_iter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57697614/8858995)*

Comment: You could also consider implementing `From<Card>` for `CardsConnectionEdge`. This would allow to simplify the conversion code to `cards.into_iter().map(From::from).collect()` (no explicit type hints needed).