# Reduce boolean Iterator

Tags: rust, functional-programming, iterator

How can I reduce an `Iterator` of booleans using the `&&` operator? Here is an example (just the relevant part):

```rust
let row: Vec<(u32, bool)> = vec![(12, true), (13, false), (15, true)];

row.iter()
    .map(|it| {
        let (_, marked) = it;
        marked
    })
    .reduce(|acc, mk | acc && mk);
```

The compiler recommends dereferencing `acc` first, then dereferencing `mk`, and finally borrowing the whole expression. It's a quite simple operation but I'm unable to find the Rustacean way to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between iter and into\_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter)

Comment: Not exaclty. Using into_iter to iterate in this case still yielding references to bool in map operation.

Comment: @salpreh [It doesn't](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4ad74dbe2cd5612e25bd1e1a31e9c497).

Comment: You're right @ChayimFriedman, sorry Colonel Thirty Two. When I tested that option agains my full code (which iterates agains a ref to a Vec unwrapped from an Optional) I ended up with the same compiler error. But that solution totally works in the isolated case I posted.

Comment: I'd recommend using [`all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all) or [`any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any), which, unlike `fold` or `reduce`, provide short-circuiting behavior.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but your call to `map` could be tidied up: `.map(|it| { it.1 })`

Comment: @Chris And even `.map(|it| it.1)`, or `.map(|(_, marked)| marked)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution that uses `fold` to specify an initial value:

```rust
let val: bool = row.iter()
    .map(|it| {
        let (_, marked) = it;
        marked
    })
    .fold(true, |acc, mk| acc && *mk);
```

The reason `acc && mk` doesn't work is because you have an iterator over `&bool` but you want a `bool`. `*acc && *mk` doesn't work because the accumulator is of type `bool`, so you want `acc && *mk`. However, you can no longer use `reduce` since the accumulator and values aren't the same type (`bool` vs `&bool`), hence the need for `fold`.

Also note that `fold` and `map` can be combined:

```rust
let val: bool = row.iter()
    .fold(true, |acc, (_, mk)| acc && *mk);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because There are three common methods which can create iterators from a collection;

```
iter(), which iterates over &T.
iter_mut(), which iterates over &mut T.
into_iter(), which iterates over T.
```

Your code uses iter (), so the iteration is & type, so you need to use & to extract value

Maybe you can do it like this:

```
    let row: Vec<(u32, bool)> = vec![(12, true), (13, false), (15, true)];

    let op = row.iter()
        .map(|&it| {
            let (_, marked) = it;
            marked // No dereference is required
        })
        .reduce(|acc, mk| acc && mk);
    println!("{:?}",op);
```

or

```
    let row: Vec<(u32, bool)> = vec![(12, true), (13, false), (15, true)];

    let op = row.into_iter()
        .map(|it| {
            let (_, marked) = it;
            marked // No dereference is required
        })
        .reduce(|acc, mk| acc && mk);
    println!("{:?}",op);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest is below. Using this [reference pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#reference-patterns); you can also destructure
the tuple inline, whereas [`fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) is a bit like `reduce`, except that you won't get constrained to `Option<Self::Item>` as return type, and have to provide an initial value, etc.

```
let result = row
    .iter()
    .map(|(_, marked)| marked)
    .fold(true, |acc, &mk| acc && mk);
```

`result` will be of type `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

After trying things the best solution I found is dereferencing value returned in previous map, so instead of returning a reference to boolean returns an owned copy. Here is the modified question code:

```rust
let row: Vec<(u32, bool)> = vec![(12, true), (13, false), (15, true)];

row.iter()
    .map(|it| {
        let (_, marked) = it;
        *marked // Dereference here
    })
    .reduce(|acc, mk | acc && mk);
```