# Checking for values in Vectors of strings in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm just getting started with Rust and have hit upon an issue where I'm getting a bit lost in types, pointers, borrowing and ownership.

I have a vector of `Person` structs, each of which has a `name` property. I'd like to collect all the names into another vector, and then check if that list contains a given string.

This is my code:

```rs
struct Person {
    name: String,
}

fn main() {
    let people = vec![Person {
        name: String::from("jack"),
    }];
    
    let names: Vec<_> = people.iter().map(|p| p.name).collect();

    let some_name = String::from("bob");
    if names.iter().any(|n| n == some_name) {
    }
}
```

This fails to compile:

```
error[E0277]: can't compare `&String` with `String`
  --> src/main.rs:13:31
   |
13 |     if names.iter().any(|n| n == some_name) {
   |                               ^^ no implementation for `&String == String`
   |
   = help: the trait `PartialEq<String>` is not implemented for `&String`
```

I think names should have the type `Vec<String>`, so I'm a bit lost as to where the `&String` comes from. Is this a case of me holding it wrong? I'm most familiar with JavaScript so I'm trying to apply those patterns, and may be not doing it in the most "rusty" way!

Comment: If you're using VSCode, I'd recommend turning on rust-analyzer's "inlay hints" feature. It will add some virtual text that adds types to some contexts. For example, here, it would change `|p| p.name` to look like `|p: &String| p.name`, which hopefully helps show where there references are coming from (don't worry, it doesn't change the actual text, it just changes the visual representation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between iter and into\_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter)

Answer (score 2):

The type of `p` is not `Person` but `&Person`, i.e. a *reference* to a value. In JavaScript there are no structs. The closest alternative is an *object* and JS objects are always stored in the *heap* and are accessed via references (although that's less explicit). In Rust you really need to think more about the memory layout of your data. That can complicate parts of your code, but it also gives you power and allows for better performance.

Here is a correct version of your code:

```
struct Person {
    name: String,
}

fn main() {
    let people = vec![Person {
        name: String::from("jack"),
    }];
    
    let names: Vec<_> = people.iter().map(|p| &p.name).cloned().collect();
    

    let some_name = String::from("bob");
    if names.iter().any(|n| n == &some_name) {
    }
}
```

Notice that in `n == &some_name` we are now comparing a `&String` with a `&String`.

Also note I added `.cloned()`, so that you avoid another error, related to *moving* the `name` strings.

A slightly more optimized version would be to only collect the references to the names, like this:

```
    let names: Vec<_> = people.iter().map(|p| &p.name).collect();   
    let some_name = String::from("bob");
    if names.iter().any(|n| *n == &some_name) {
    }
```

Note that in this version `n` is of type `&&String`, so we *dereference* it once via `*n`. That way we are again comparing a `&String` with a `&String`. Rust also allows you to write something like this: `|&n| n == &some_name`, which is practically the same.

Answer (score 2):

Several things going on there:

1. `&String` comes from the fact that `iter()` iterates over the collection without consuming it, and therefore can only give you *references* into items of the collection.
2. You can address the inability to compare `&String` to `String` by borrowing the latter, i.e. changing `n == some_name` to `n == &some_name`.
3. After you do that, the compiler will tell you that `p.name` attempts to move `name` out of the reference `p`. To get rid of it, you can change `p.name` to `&p.name`, thus creating a `Vec<&String>`.
4. ...after which `n` will become `&&String` (!), so you'll need `n == &&some_name`. The example then compiles.

Comment: About pt 1: in his code `p` is `&Person`, but he gets (moves) the names, so he actually collects a `Vec<String>`, not `Vec<&String>`, right?

Comment: @at54321 Yes. More precisely, the OP _attempts_ to collect `Vec<String>`, but that can't work (without cloning `p.name`, which isn't warranted here), except that error is hidden by the other error reported in the question. The answer tries to disentangle that piece by piece.

Answer (score 1):

Because Rust does not `impl PartialEq<&String> for String` by default, here are `impl PartialEq<&String> for &String` and `impl PartialEq<String> for String`.

Here the type of `n` is `&String`, the type of `some_name` is `String`, so you need to balance the references on the left and right side of `==`.

Both of the following fixes work. I prefer the first one, because the second one has a dereference which implies extra overhead for me. I'm not sure if Rust explicitly defines that there won't be overhead here, and even if there is, LLVM can usually optimize it.

```rust
if names.iter().any(|n| n == &some_name) // &String == &String
// or
if names.iter().any(|n| *n == some_name) // String == String
```

Then you will encounter another error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `p.name` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:10:47
   |
10 |     let names: Vec<_> = people.iter().map(|p| p.name).collect();
   |                                               ^^^^^^ move occurs because `p.name` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
```

`|p| p.name` tries to move the `name` out of `p`, which is not necessary for the later checks, a `&str` is enough here. Returns the `&str` of a `String` via [`String::as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_str): `|p| p.name.as_str()`

Because of this fix, the type of `n` below becomes `&&str`, you can use `names.into_iter()` to get an iterator for ownership of `names`.

Fixed code:

```rust
struct Person {
    name: String,
}

fn main() {
    let people = vec![Person {
        name: String::from("jack"),
    }];
    
    let names: Vec<_> = people.iter().map(|p| p.name.as_str()).collect();

    let some_name = String::from("bob");
    if names.into_iter().any(|n| n == some_name) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your version compiles, but it's probably worth noting that your `names` implementation *moves* (*consumes*) `people` (due to the `into_iter()` call), so it cannot be used anymore.

Comment: @at54321 Thanks, I realized I was lost in fixing error messages. I have edited the answer.