# How to determine whether to use .clone() and .cloned() with iterators

Tags: rust

Suppose we have a vector of some type that can be cloned

```rust
let foo_vec = vec![clonable_item_1, clonable_item_2, ...];
```

How to determine whether to use `.clone()` and `.cloned()` when iterating?

```rust
foo_vec.iter().cloned()...

// vs

foo_vec.clone().iter()...
```

I couldn't find anything written about the difference between the two. What's the difference?

Comment: As per the linked answer, `foo_vec.iter().cloned()` is like doing `foo_vec.iter().map(|x| x.clone())`, which is indeed different from first cloning the vector and iterating on that copy. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter

Comment: `foo_vec.clone().iter()` should be avoided if possible since it clones the entire vector up front, using up a lot of memory, whereas `foo_vec.iter().cloned()` only clones the items one at a time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They're not at all equal. If anything, it should be `v.iter().cloned()` vs. `v.clone().into_iter()`, both produce an iterator over owned `T` while `v.clone().iter()` produces an iterator over `&T`.

`v.clone().into_iter()` clones the `Vec`, allocating a `Vec` with the same size and cloning all elements into it, then converts this newly created `Vec` into an iterator. `v.iter().cloned()`, OTOH, creates a borrowed iterator over the `Vec` that yields `&T`, then applies the `cloned()` iterator adapter to it, which on-the-fly clones the `&T` produced by `Iterator::next()` to produce an owned `T`. Thus it doesn't need to allocate a new vector.

Because of that, you should always prefer `v.iter().cloned()` when possible (usually it is, but `Vec`'s `IntoIter` has additional capabilities, like [getting the underlying slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.IntoIter.html#method.as_slice) that may be required).