# Avoid duplicates in nested for loop

Tags: rust

I have the following nested for loop in Rust:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Tes2 {
    a: Vec<String>,
    b: Vec<Vec<String>>,
}

fn vectes() {
    let mut ff: Vec<Tes2> = Vec::new();

    let one = vec![
        vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string()],
        vec!["x".to_string(), "y".to_string()],
    ];

    let two = vec![
        vec![
            vec!["d".to_string(), "e".to_string()],
            vec!["g".to_string(), "h".to_string()],
            vec!["j".to_string(), "k".to_string()],
        ],
        vec![
            vec!["mm".to_string(), "nn".to_string()],
            vec!["oo".to_string(), "pq".to_string()],
            vec!["rr".to_string(), "ss".to_string()],
        ],
    ];

    for i in one {
        for (mut k, j) in two.clone().into_iter().enumerate() {
            if k != 1 {
                ff.push(Tes2 { a: i.clone(), b: j });
            }
            k += 1;
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", ff);
}
```

The output of which is:

```
[Tes2 { a: ["a", "b"], b: [["d", "e"], ["g", "h"], ["j", "k"]] }, Tes2 { a: ["x", "y"], b: [["d", "e"], ["g", "h"], ["j", "k"]] }]
```

This is what I want and is correct. Essentially, in each new struct I am trying to pair `one[0]` with `two[0]` and then `one[1]` with `two[1]` etc.

I am sure there is a much more real and efficient "Rust way" to do this, maybe with the map method, and avoiding for loops altogether, but I have tried in different ways and it never worked.

Comment: You probably need [`std::iter::zip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/fn.zip.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're looking for is [`Iterator::zip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.zip) (or since Rust 1.59.0, [`std::iter::zip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/fn.zip.html)).

```rust
for (a, b) in std::iter::zip(one, two) {
    ff.push(Tes2 { a, b })
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=720fa8e0a3df3dc78769aa9ca83624dd).

At that time, you can avoid using a loop altogether and just use [`collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect):

```rust
let ff: Vec<_> = std::iter::zip(one, two)
    .map(|(a, b)| Tes2 { a, b })
    .collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=483830233b2a086aa27594f6a2f01994).

Of course, a simple loop will always work:

```rust
for i in 0..one.len() {
    ff.push(Tes2 {
        a: one[i].clone(),
        b: two[i].clone(),
    });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3021aedcb6be7b600d44acfa81cbed80).

As a side note, it's better to use `.iter().clone()` than `.clone().into_iter()`. See [How to determine whether to use .clone() and .cloned() with iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71235663/how-to-determine-whether-to-use-clone-and-cloned-with-iterators/).