# Issue with reduce() in Rust for summing square perimeters, fold() works

Tags: rust, reduce, fold

I encountered an issue while trying to use the `reduce()` method in Rust to calculate the sum of perimeters of squares. The problem is based on a drawing where there are `n + 1` squares arranged with side lengths following the Fibonacci sequence. For example, if `n = 5`, the side lengths of the squares are [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]. The task is to find the sum of the perimeters of these squares.

Initially, I implemented the code using the `fold()` method, and it worked correctly. Here's the code snippet that uses `fold()`:

```rust
fn perimeter(n: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut fib = vec![1, 1];
    for i in 2..=n as usize {
        fib.push(fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2]);
    }

    // Calculate the sum of the perimeters using the fold method
    fib.iter().fold(0, |acc, val| acc + val * 4)
}
```

However, when I tried to refactor the code to use the `reduce()` method, it failed to compile. I modified the code as follows:

```rust
fn perimeter(n: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut fib = vec![1, 1];
    for i in 2..=n as usize {
        fib.push(fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2]);
    }

    // Calculate the sum of the perimeters using the reduce method
    fib.iter().reduce(|acc, val| acc + val * 4).unwrap()
}
```

When using the reduce() method, I encountered the following error message:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:8:34
  |
8 |     fib.iter().reduce(|acc, val| acc + val * 4).unwrap()
  |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |                                  |
  |                                  expected `&{integer}`, found integer
  |                                  help: consider borrowing here: `&(acc + val * 4)`
```

I have read the Rust documentation for `reduce()` and found an example where it works correctly. Here's the example from the documentation:

```rust
let reduced: i32 = (1..10).reduce(|acc, e| acc + e).unwrap();
assert_eq!(reduced, 45);

// Which is equivalent to doing it with `fold`:
let folded: i32 = (1..10).fold(0, |acc, e| acc + e);
assert_eq!(reduced, folded);
```

I expected the code to compile successfully and produce the same result as the `fold()` implementation. However, the error message suggests a mismatched type issue with the `reduce()` method.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully use the `reduce()` method to calculate the sum of perimeters of the squares. Alternatively, if there is a reason why `reduce()` cannot be used in this scenario, I would like to understand it.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: @Stargateur: While this question is solvable by using `.into_iter()` instead of `.iter()`, that's not the only solution, and the duplicate doesn't in any way address the implications of the choice when it comes to `fold` vs. `reduce` (the error from `reduce` is pretty useless, since it suggests solving the issue by creating a new one, using references to expiring temporaries). This should not have been closed as a duplicate of [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34733811/364696)

Comment: your answer when I close was "use into_iter()" so allow me to disagree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that `fold` is provided a by-value accumulator explicitly (that initial `0`), so the input to each stage, and the output from each stage, is by value; everything agrees, so it's fine.

`reduce` is using the first output from the iterator as the first `acc`, and by using `.iter()`, you are passing it a reference to a value (one still owned by the original `Vec`). Since `acc` itself begins as such a reference to the first value in the `Vec`, you have the problem of receiving a reference on the first call, and trying to produce a value to be used for `acc` for the second call, so `acc` has an inconsistent type (reference on first invocation, value for all others).

The easiest solution here is to just consume the expiring `Vec` by using `.into_iter()` to iterate (and consume) the values directly, rather than iterating references to them:

```rust
fn perimeter(n: u64) -> u64 {
    let mut fib = vec![1, 1];
    for i in 2..=n as usize {
        fib.push(fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2]);
    }

    // Calculate the sum of the perimeters using the reduce method
    fib.into_iter().reduce(|acc, val| acc + val * 4).unwrap()
    //  ^^^^^ Only change
}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVBBTsMwEBTXvGLakw1JSqMIIVC58AAeUBXkuk5jyXEixy6CNi_h0gM8Cl6D4ySIvex4vbuzMx-fxrX2fP5ytkhufy5IodEIIythhSH6Du4mp0ge-oxjBB9KWFTOopBbrHAQfLZexlhu7sNvURtISI0sTVcarIVr5bsYZ0OH3KaNa0viwVoi8aO4wvTINnRY1EUhLRZ4ZIo7xayALQVaV6EuAvw7NJDofSgasXNcwNfLehdNhFLb-kX2mmg6dJAT4zzGgakTPPIneIhL5DR1-tWwhtDpADz3gSet3sBLpvci6gbDvq-9XxWTmtBRYWM8ldIzMj928_ifl1lOvbJxbjL8Fw)

If the `Vec` cannot be consumed, other easy options for copyable/clonable types would be to make the iterator into a copying or cloning iterator, e.g.:

```
fib.iter().copied().reduce(|acc, val| acc + val * 4).unwrap()
// or
fib.iter().cloned().reduce(|acc, val| acc + val * 4).unwrap()
```

but frankly, `fold` is generally a better solution, unless you *want* to fail loudly when the underlying iterator is empty, since it guarantees a result (avoiding the need to `.unwrap()` or otherwise deal with the empty iterator case), doesn't require consuming, copying or cloning, and, as noted in the comments, actually does what you intended (computing the sum of all the values multiplied by four, where `reduce` fails to multiply the first value by four, since it's used as the original `acc` value, never as `val`).

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanations and providing alternative methods to solve the problem. I tried implementing your suggestions in my program, and while it compiled smoothly, the results were always off by 3 compared to the version using the `fold()` method.

For instance, `perimeter(5)` yields 80 with `fold()`, but `reduce()` with `into_iter()` gives 77, which is off by 3.

I attempted the other methods you mentioned, but encountered the same discrepancy. Only the `fold()` method consistently provided the correct result. Could there be any other factors at play here?

Comment: When you use `reduce()` the first value in the vector (1) is not multiplied by four; it is instead used for the initial value of the accumulator.

Comment: @NathanielVerhaaren Ohhhhh, I finally get it! Thanks to your explanation, it all makes sense now. You're amazing.