# How to get the index of the current element being processed in the iteration without a for loop?

Tags: rust

I have read [How to iterate a Vec<T> with the indexed position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991050/how-to-iterate-a-vect-with-the-indexed-position) where the answer is to use `enumerate` in a `for`-loop.

But if I don't use a `for`-loop like this:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1; 10]
        .iter()
        .map(|&x| x + 1  /* + index */ ) // <--
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    print!("v{:?}", v);
}
```

How could I get the index in the above closure?

Comment: Why do you believe that `enumerate` will not work outside of a `for` loop?

Comment: As soon as I posted it I realized the answer

Comment: `enumerate` is not magical nor tied to `for`. It's just a function which returns an iterator over tuples. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate

Comment: Who deleted my comment here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also use `enumerate`!

```rust
let v = vec![1; 10]
    .iter()
    .enumerate()
    .map(|(i, &x)| x + i)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();

println!("v{:?}", v);   // prints v[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

---

Let's see how this works. [`Iterator::enumerate`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) returns [`Enumerate<Self>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/iter/struct.Enumerate.html). That type also implements `Iterator`:

```rust
impl<I> Iterator for Enumerate<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
{
    type Item = (usize, <I as Iterator>::Item);
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, the new iterator yields tuples of the index and the original 
value.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use `enumerate`:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1; 10]
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, x)| i + x)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    print!("v{:?}", v);
}
```

The reason for this is because the for loop takes an enumerator:
In slightly more abstract terms:

```
for var in expression {
    code
}
```

[The expression is an iterator.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.1.0/book/for-loops.html)

Comment: Hint: if you plan on self-answering your question, in [the "asking" form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), there is a "answer your own question" checkbox at the bottom. That way, your answer appears the exact same moment your question is posted.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. I realized like 5 seconds after I posted

Comment: Ah ok, I understand :D